# Is it possible to continuously feed parallel with more input?

Tags: parallelism, gnu-parallel, inotify

What I want to do is something like this:

```
inotifywait -m ./input -e close_write -e moved_to |
    parallel --max-args 1 "someSlowSingleThreadedTaskThatActsOnThisFile"
```

I can't imagine that that would work as-is (it [doesn't seem to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/635717/how-to-use-parallel-with-inotifywait)). I assume `parallel` has to be given all of its inputs at the start, before it begins running. Therefore my question is this: Is there a way that I could add more inputs to parallel as it's already going? I imagine the inputs as a pool of work, and it just processes that pool as fast as possible, using the maximum sensible number of threads for the current system. What I want to do is add to that pool while it's still going.

How can I continuously feed `parallel` with more inputs as it's running (specifically, as more files are added to the folder)? Alternatively, if `parallel` isn't a good choice for this task, what is?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `entr` command you supply `entr` a file or list of files and then whenever a change to that file is made it runs an arbitrary command.  Would this help I use it to rebuild previews and projects automatically when the files are changed.  I don't see why you couldn't use `parallel` with it.

Jason C.

Comment: This is what `inotifywait` already does. The issue is not finding a way to run a command when the directory changes, but rather finding a way to process those files in parallel while still being able to add to the "pool" of files left to be processed.